# Merge meshes with materials Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to merge meshes in Three.js. Meshes are loaded from a COLLADA model exported from Blender. Here's the model loaded without merging:

Plain model:
[image]

When I try to merge the meshes this is what I get:
Merged model:
[image]

I think I'm having problems with materials UVs, because I get 288 warning messages like:

```
THREE.DirectGeometry.fromGeometry(): Undefined vertexUv 99945
```

with the number going from 99945 to 100232.

Here's the code I use to merge the meshes:

```
    loader.load(modelPath, function(model)
    {
        var modelShape = model.scene;

        var materialsArray = new Array();
        var mergedGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        var materialIndex = 0;

        modelShape.traverse(function(mesh)
        {
            if(mesh instanceof THREE.Mesh && typeof mesh.material !== "undefined")
            {
                var modelGeometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(mesh.geometry);
                modelGeometry.mergeVertices();

                mergedGeometry.merge(modelGeometry, mesh.matrix, materialIndex);
                materialsArray[materialIndex] = mesh.material;

                materialIndex++;
            }
        });

        mergedGeometry.mergeVertices();
        mergedGeometry.rotateX(-90 * Math.PI / 180);

        var modifier = new THREE.SubdivisionModifier(subdivisions);
        var geometrySmoothed = mergedGeometry;

        mergedGeometry.groupsNeedUpdate = true;
        mergedGeometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometrySmoothed, materialsArray);

        this.models.push(mesh);
    }
```

So, does anybody know where is the error? Could it be an error exporting from Blender?

Comment: May have an easier time merging this in Blender ("Join") before export, is that possible? If you get rid of the last few steps — `.mergeVertices` and `SubdivisionModifier` — does it work better? [BufferGeometryUtils](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/BufferGeometryUtils) may also be helpful.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I tried merging in Blender, but I have models with a lot of meshes and it took me too much time. I put the code with `SubdivisionModifier`, but has you can see I don't use it (but I will) and if I remove `.mergeVertices` nothing changes. Anyway I'll take a look at BufferGeometryUtils, thank you

Comment: I figured out that I'm merging some meshes with uvs with others without uvs, so probably I have to add uvs to the second ones...